Copying data from repeated cells in multiple excel files in a folder to a new file as a table not entering the loops
There's a few iterations/versions of code from StackOverflow that I have tried to copy certain repeated cells from multiple excel files in a folder into one new file. From adding MsgBox into different parts of the loop it seems that the code doesnt enter the Do loop but Im not quite sure why? Any suggestions? I assume it is related to the snippets of lines I have attached below:
' Loop through all Excel files in the folder
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsm*")
Do While fileName <> ""
    ' Open the workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)
    MsgBox ("you have opened a workbook")

*i have verified that the folder path is correct. one comment/note about that was I was ensure if the folder paths have to be within C:\ something or they can be external drives? Ive tried both but that doesnt seem to be the issue.
Any help is appreciated thanks!

What kind of value is in folderPath ?  Does it end in \ ?

the end of the folder path is \2024... after looking on the internet a bit further it appears I may need the backslash at the end

update: the code now runs when there is a backlash at the end! sorry for the lizard brain!

Good to hear you got it working.
